# ESLint warning (should use method for non-callbacks) - How to treat that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How can I solve this warning from ESLint?

I have an event listener for resize inside componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeEditor);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeEditor);
}
```

And my method to update on Resize:

```
resizeEditor = () => {
   if (this.editor) this.editor.layout();
}
```

It's working like this, but I'm getting a warning:

> [eslint] should use method for non-callbacks [class-prefer-methods/prefer-methods]

If I change the arrow function to:

```
resizeEditor() {
   if (this.editor) this.editor.layout();
}
```

Of course It won't find **this.editor**. It's out of the scope.

If I try to pass the editor to my resize function:

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.resizeEditor(this.editor));

 resizeEditor(editor) {
   if (editor) editor.layout();
 }
```

I'm getting another warning:

> [eslint] Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'resizeEditor'. [class-methods-use-this]

So, I'm kind blocked here what path follow to not get these warnings.

Thanks!

Comment: This is just my opinion, but how much should you care about ESLint anyway? So long as the code is clear in what it does (and works!) then what's the problem? Don't intentionally butcher perfectly acceptable code just to confirm to the opinions of ESLint's developers.

Comment: Maybe configure ESLint to behave how you like so that it doesn't become a habit to leave warnings though

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I take a somewhat opposed stance here but I'd still agree with you. Bottom line - don't change the code. *Change the rule*. This is not up to the ESLint developers but personal preference. All the rules are configurable to make them whatever you want - ESLint ships with default config but I don't think this rule is even among them.

Comment: In my opinion, `window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.resizeEditor(this.editor));` is kinda wrong. `addEventListener` binds element as context. Using arrow function beats this feature.

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.resizeEditor.bind(this));` Check the discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3q63i1/es6_classes_bind_method_to_event_the_clean_way/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you have such a good point. I did this in some parts of the code, but this one I got curious to know how do they solve this.

Comment: @NoelKriegler, not working, it doesn't find the this.editor inside. Thanks.

Comment: @ItaloBorges sorry I ment `window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeEditor.bind(this));`